# Why not synthesize move operations for a class that defines the destructor as =default?

Tags: c++, c++11

The rule that the compiler shouldn't synthesize move operations for a class that declares a destructor or a copy operation (i.e. copy constructor/assignment) makes sense. Afterall, by declaring these operations, the class admits that it needs to do some custom bookkeeping.

However, this reasoning does not apply when the class defines the destructor or a copy operation as `=default`? Shouldn't then this case be an exception from the rule?

EDIT: One reason I might want to define the destructor as `=default`, but not the other special operations, is when I need a virtual destructor for the base class, so I am forced to define one to make it virtual.

Comment: Defaulting a copy operation and not deleting a move operation gives the class the unique property of being both copyable and movable, while potentially remaining trivially copyable.

Comment: @dyp wouldn't explicitly defaulted move operations also mean it can remain trivially-copyable?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, but a defaulted move ctor means that moving the object actually *moves*, whereas a non-existing move ctor means it'll be copied. I don't think this matters for trivially copyable types, though.

Comment: See [N3053](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3053.html) "A struct move is implicitly declared if it is well-formed and the corresponding copy is not user-declared. So, explicitly defaulting a copy constructor will supress the move constructor. One can add the move constructor back by explicitly defaulting it. Doing otherwise would require deleting the move, which leaves a hole in the expressions." That doesn't explain the behaviour for dtors, though.

Comment: Also relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3174.pdf which introduced the *user-declared dtor -> no implicit move ctor*

Answer (score 4):

[N3174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3174.pdf) seems to have been the proposal that introduced the rule *user-declared dtor/copy op => no implicit move*. In this paper, Bjarne Stroustrup shows concern for certain class invariants, as in:

> ```
> class Vec {
>     vector<int> v;
>     int my_int;    // the index of my favorite int stored in v
>     // implicit/generated copy, move, and destructor
>     // ...
> };
> ```
>
> `Vec` has what I call an *implicit invariant*: There is a relation
>   between two objects (here, the members) that is nowhere stated in
>   declaratively in the code.

Note that this invariant is broken by move operations, which is especially evil if they're implicitly generated, and change the meaning of code that was formerly well-behaved (in C++03 where rvalues are copied).

Because of these invariants, Stroustrup proposed:

> 1. Move and  copy are generated by default (if an only if their elements move or copy as currently specified in the FCD [dyp: FCD =
>      final committee draft])
> 2. If any move, copy, or destructor is explicitly specified (declared, defined, `=default`, or `=delete`) by the user, no copy or move is
>      generated by default.

(Later, he suggests to only deprecate implicit generation of copy in 2., not remove it entirely in C++11)

The best explanation I can find in N3174 why defaulted user-declared operations are included in the second bullet point is the relation between invariants and special member functions:

> I think that the most worrying cases are equivalent to `Vec`. For such
>   classes there is an implicit invariant but no “indication” to help the
>   compiler [dyp: discover the existence of an invariant] in the form of a user-specified copy constructor. This kind
>   of example occurs (occurred) when a programmer decided that the
>   default copy operations were correct and then (correctly) decided not
>   to mention them because the default copy operations are superior to
>   user-defined ones (e.g. because of ABI issues). In C++0x, a programmer
>   can be explicit by defaulting  copy, but that could be considered
>   undesirably verbose.

So by writing `Vec` as follows:

```
class Vec {
    vector<int> v;
    int my_int;    // the index of my favorite int stored in v
public:
    Vec() = default;
    Vec(Vec const&) = default;
    Vec& operator=(Vec const&) = default;
    ~Vec() = default;
};
```

we can state that the *default* copy operations are safe, while the default move operations are not safe. If the user had to explicitly define the move operations as deleted, this would "leave[..] a hole in the expressions" (see [N3053](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3053.html#Proposal): trying to copy from, or return (non-const) rvalues will attempt to use the deleted move operations.

It is not entirely obvious why the dtor should be included in that list, but I think it belongs to the group of 3/5 special member functions where class invariants often occur.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the reason is that if you've written a defaulted destructor then you are already writing (at least) C++11 and so there is no reason you should not be able to also write a defaulted move constructor and move assignment operator.

The rule protects against classes written pre-C++11 from silently being given move semantics that might break the class invariants. If the class is not pre-C++11 then you can decide explicitly whether you want move semantics and enable them with `=default`.

Comment: I might have been forced to define a destructor, because I need a virtual destructor for the base class and the default one is not virtual. But I certainly don't want to define all 5 special member functions!

Comment: You don't need to, you just say `A(A&&) = default;`, but the idea is that it's better to be explicit about what you want (by declaring them as defaulted) than having things declared implicitly. Even implicitly defined copy constructors are deprecated in C++11, the idea being that in some future standard you will have to explicitly default the copy constructor to get the compiler to define it.

Comment: I kinda think they're often too terse actually.

Comment: As the Zen of Python says, explicit is better than implicit. And adding those few tokens hardly increases verbosity.

Comment: How does this rule protect pre-C++11 classes? There is no `=default` keyword prior to C++11, is there?

Comment: Regarding verbosity: By adding `A(const A&)=default;` you tell readers of the code that you have thought about it and decided explicitly that letting the compiler generate that function is correct for your class. If you don't do that readers have to consider whether you intended it to use the implicit copy ctor or are just a sloppy developer who forgot to write a copy ctor.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg, tha'ts exactly my point! Because `=default` isn't valid  in C++03 a class with `~A()=default;` **is not a legacy class written pre-C++11**, so it's reasonable to expect that author/maintainer of the class to also add `A(&&)=default;` if that's what they want. If you want to write `~A()=default;` and also want your class to have a move constructor then declare one and default it.

Comment: To put it another way, the rule "suppress move operations if there is a user-declared destructor" protects legacy classes, and doesn't greatly hurt non-legacy classes using `~A()=default;` like your situation because you can easily solve it by just adding `A(&&)=default;`